# Is it correct to use t-test on accuracy values of two different classifiers?

Tags: classification, accuracy, t-test

I have two datasets (500 data points with 15 variables and a binary output):
The first one includes all variables.
The second one includes all variables, except one is removed.
I want to check the importance of that specific variable on my accuracy.

Apart from checking Shap, Lime etc. to assess the importance of each variable, I did the following:
I trained 100 classifiers (log-reg., with cross-validation) on each dataset.
I took the two accuracy populations and performed a t-test to check that they are not coming from the same distribution by check the p-value.

Is such procedure correct? Somehow, I had no other better idea to compare the two groups of accuracies that I got.

Is it also possible/better to perform bootstrapping by approximating the distribution of the mean for these two populations, and after that perform the t-test?

Comment: In the way that you framed the question, it probably seems correct, though I am not sure t-test is the appropriate way to compare accuracies (not sure you can call their distribution normal). I wonder whether a more reasonable question to ask would be whether your your one extra variable carries unique information that helps to reduce residuals, i.e. once you fit your classifiers, predict, and extract the error between prediction and actual output, is that correlated with your one variable (if you did not use it in prediction)?